# Can't Close the infowindow with googlemap

Tags: google-maps, infowindow

```
var markers = {};
var openedInfoWindow = null;    

function addDoctorLocation(options) 
{
    var gm = Ext.getCmp('mygooglemap');
    var mpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(options.lat,options.lng);
    var marker = gm.addMarker(mpoint,options.marker,false,false, options.listeners);
    markers[options.MainID] = marker;

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "Hello from this marker"
  });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      if (openedInfoWindow != null) openedInfoWindow.close();  // <-- changed this
      infowindow.open(map, marker); 
      // added next 4 lines
      openedInfoWindow = infowindow;
      google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
          openedInfoWindow = null;
      });
    });
}
```

when clicked infowindow close button, nothing happen.
This code when clicked the marker will get this error,but info window are proper display on gmappanel

```
TypeError: b.O is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

(82 out of range 43)
```

Comment: Do you have a link to a map that exhibits the problem (or a jsfiddle)?

Comment: @geocodezip no..i dont have

Answer (score 0):

Have a reading here about the [Info Window](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows).